# Android continues loop for animation

Tags: java, android, xml, loops, animation

I have tried several kinds of looping in my animation based on the answers here such as animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); or android:repeatcount="infinite" in the anim.xml file..even tried the while(true) loop on java but none seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="3000" />

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0.0"
    android:toXDelta="0.0"
    android:fromYDelta="0.0"
    android:toYDelta="100.0"
    android:startOffset="3000"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"/>

</set>
```

and the my java is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.halloweenanim);

    img.startAnimation(animation);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

    //hallo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.halloweenimg);
    //animation2 = (AnimationDrawable) hallo.getBackground();
    //animation2 = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
    //animation.start();
};
```

Comment: I am not getting what does not seems to work?

Comment: i mean continuous loop. it only animates once and then nothing happens. i would like to keep it animating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually AnimationSet has a buggy code. Even the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) says

> repeatCount, fillEnabled: These properties are ignored for
>   AnimationSet.

What you can do is remove `animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);`
and set `android:repeatCount="infinite"` for each of your animation tag, instead of the parent set tag.

Answer (score 1):

nevermind. i found the solution. the android:repeatCount="infinite" should be placed inside the alpha lol. and no need to add .setRepeatCount inside the java code. XD

Comment: yes you have to add the attribute individually in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this and look whether it helps you.

```
animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.halloweenanim);
 animation.setAnimationListener(this);
                img.startAnimation(animation);
    }

});
 img.startAnimation(animation);
```